# Nant COM Reference

Tags: nant, build

I'm trying to find the Nant syntax for including a COM reference.

The current Nant script with the normal dll reference looks like ..

```
<references>
    <include name="${external-lib}/System.Interop.AppName.dll" />
```

The COM reference in the .csproj file looks like this ...

```
<COMReference Include="System.Interop.AppName">
  <Guid>{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}</Guid>
  <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
  <VersionMinor>7</VersionMinor>
  <Lcid>0</Lcid>
  <WrapperTool>primary</WrapperTool>
  <Isolated>False</Isolated>
</COMReference>
```

What syntax should I use in Nant to swap to the COM reference to do the build ?

Answer (score 0):

Use tlbimp (nant task) and reference the generated assembly instead.